# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mongodb.dll'

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, xampp, composer-php

I'm trying to get Laravel MongoDB working in my local machine (Windows 10 home, x64) by following [this tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/05/10/laravel-mongodb-crud-tutorial-with-example/)

1. I have installed XAMPP 7.3.11 on `D:\xampp` succesfully and tested that the server can be reached (enter `localhost:80` on browser)
2. I proceeded on extracting `php_mongodb.dll` I got from [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.6.0/windows)(mongodb 1.6.0 for Windows, 7.3 Non Thread Safe, x64 ) on `D:\xampp\php\ext` and add the line `extension=php_mongodb.dll` on the file `D:\xampp\php\php.ini`
3. After selecting 'the command-line PHP you want to use' to `D:\xampp\php\php.exe`, the setup then gave the following output:

   > The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
   >   D:\xampp\php\php.exe
   >
   > The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: D:\xampp\php\php.ini
   >
   > A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the
   >   'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.
   >
   > Program Output: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
   >   library 'php_mongodb.dll' (tried: D:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll
   >   (The specified module could not be found.),
   >   D:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mongodb.dll.dll (The specified module could
   >   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Commenting out the line `extension=php_mongodb.dll` will execute `D:\xampp\php\php.exe` without any warning. But I would need php to be aware of `php_mongodb.dll` during composer installation, right?

So how to resolve this problem? The file definitely exists in the folder, and the required modification on `php.ini` has been provided. 
I have already looked around and some people mentioning the path in `extension_dir` must be written in full path. But I have already checked that the line on my `php.ini` is `extension_dir="D:\xampp\php\ext"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem resolved.

**Cause: I was using Non Thread Safe `php_mongodb.dll`, while the PHP installed by XAMPP is a Thread Safe one.**

After replacing `php_mongodb.dll` with the thread safe version, there's no error and I can successfully completed composer installation.